# class array within double quotes

Tags: php, mysql

I have follow two classes

```
class A  
{     
    ....  
protected  $arr = array('game_id','pl_id');  
...  
}   
class B extends A   
{  
    //for example here add method   
   private function add_to_DB()    
  {   
      $query = "INSERT INTO TABLE(game_id,player_id)    
                     VALUES(????,????)";   //Here is my question,what I must to write??
mysql_query($query);
}  
}
```

I try to write `..VALUES(\"$this->arr[game_id]\",\"$this->arr[pl_id]\")"`, or
`VALUES(".$this->arr[game_id].",".$this->arr[pl_id].")"`
,but its does not working.

Thanks for any advise

I think I found  another solution of my question.
in my A class I must to have _*set and _* get methods.
 class A
    {
        ....
    protected  arr = array('game_id'=>NULL,'pl_id'=>NULL);

```
    function __set($property, $value)  
 {  
     if (array_key_exists($property, $this->arr)) {  
         $this->arr[$property] = $value;  
     } else {  
         print "Error: Can't write a property other than x & y\n";  
     }
 }


  function __get($property)
  {
      if (array_key_exists($property, $this->arr)) {
           return $this->arr[$property];
      } else {
          print "ERROR: write correct property";
      }
  }

...  
}
```

And after this in class B I can write the follow

private function add_to_DB()
 {
        $query = "INSERT INTO TABLE(game_id,player_id)
                       VALUES(\"$this->game_id\",\"$this->pl_id\")";   //Here WAS my question
     mysql_query($query);
}

Thanks for your advise

Comment: accept some answers, i can help you but i won't until you do so.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be use PDO_MySQL so you could [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) queries with parameters.  Then you wouldn't have to worry about quotes at all.  It's as simple as this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE (game_id, player_id) 
                       VALUES (:game_id, :pl_id)");
$stmt->execute($this->arr);
```

The plain MySQL extension for PHP doesn't support parameters in SQL queries.  If you must continue to use that API, you should at least use some technique to protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  For example, if they're integers, then coercion to int:

```
$g = (int) $this->arr["game_id"];
$p = (int) $this->arr["pl_id"];
$query = "INSERT INTO TABLE(game_id,player_id) VALUES({$g}, {$p})";
mysql_query($query);
```

If they're strings, you **must** escape the values using the provided function:

```
$g = mysql_real_escape_string($this->arr["game_id"]);
$p = mysql_real_escape_string($this->arr["pl_id"]);
$query = "INSERT INTO TABLE(game_id,player_id) VALUES('{$g}', '{$p}')";
mysql_query($query);
```

Also remember to quote your array keys or else they'll be interpreted as PHP constants, not strings.

Comment: what's difference between `VALUES('{$g}', '{$p}')` and `VALUES('$g', '$p')`? I mean why did you placed `$g` and `$p` inside {}?

Comment: @seoul, In this case, no difference,  PHP has the curly-brace syntax to allow for more complex variable references, like accessing fields of an array or an object.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a sprintf as its better for readability and typecasting

```
$query = "INSERT INTO TABLE(game_id,player_id) VALUES('%d','%d')";
$query = sprintf($query,$this->arr['game_id'],$this->arr['pl_id']);
mysql_query($query);
```

Look up the manual on what you should use and how to use sprintf, `%d` is for a digit / integer, `%s` is for string, if you use string you must also make sure your using mysql_eral_escape_string on the value to prevent SQL Injection

re looking at your question I think your on about extending objects and so on so let me just show you this example?

```
class FirstClass
{
    protected $var = "FirstClass";
}
```

if you extend the class like so:

```
class SecondClass extends FirstClass
{
    public function aMethod()
    {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}
```

this would echo the string from the class, but if i was to do the following

```
class ThirdClass extends FirstClass
{
    protected $var = "ThirdClass";

    public function aMethod()
    {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}
```

This would echo ThirdClass because you have overwritten the first variable, so as long as you do not overwrite the variable in the parent class you can just use $this like it was a member of your child class

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$query = "INSERT INTO TABLE(game_id,player_id)    
                     VALUES('".$this->arr[0]."','".$this->arr[1]."')";
```